# How to execute JavaScript in Android/JAVA-Google Maps API V3?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

In fact, all is in the title, i succeed to display Google Maps based on API V3, and now i want to add for example an overlay/icon in the map, i have the  JS script(made by google) but i don't know how to implement it in Android/JAVA? Any example please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you need to use the Google Maps JS API? i.e, are you developing a web-based application or with a web tool? Because you can simply use MapView, which will greatly ease your efforts while using GMaps for Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html .

Comment: @jcxavier: i'm trying to use Google Maps V3 because they recommand to use it now, i tried to retun to v2 because i'm familiar with it but Google can not give me an API key, so i was sure that V2 is deprecated officially and they try to obligate developers to use v3 .

Comment: @androiniennn Ok, but my point wasn't comparing the JS APIs, it was telling you that Google provides a Java API to use with Android which integrates quite seamlessly (and it's easier to use in Android than the JS API).

Comment: @jcxavier: clear ;) but what about the api key that they seems blocking it? Can't use a MapView without api key i guess ...

Comment: you are right. Here you are: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Comment: @jcxavier: here where the problem is: http://code.google.com/intl/fr/android/maps-api-signup.html when i put the MD5 to have an API key, it always blocks it. Please try it and you'll believe me :).

Comment: @jcxavier: my own MD5 that it's not working(weird,weird,weird..) : Empreinte du certificat (SHA1) : 7D:21:CD:76:3D:E3:BF:0B:99:B9:1A:7C:49:99:5F:8B:5E:C3:68:CE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8457/discussion-between-jcxavier-and-androniennn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to keep a record, the problem was that a `SHA1` key was being created by the `keytool` instead a `MD5` (that Google Maps needs to create the API key). That was happening because with the JDk 1.7 installed the `keytool` creates a SHA1 by default. The problem can be solved adding a `-v` param to the `keytool` command:

```
keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -v
```